# GPU Selection Problem in multi-GPU Background Rendering with blender-3.6.2-linux-x64

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I attempted rendering using a multi-GPU server on [vast.ai](https://vast.ai/).

I considered running one instance of Blender per GPU to utilize multiple GPU resources effectively. The Blender version is blender-3.6.2-linux-x64.

For instance, when using 2 GPUs:

- GPU 0: Rendering from Frame 1 to Frame 25
- GPU 1: Rendering from Frame 26 to Frame 50

However, in the script below, only GPU0 is being utilized.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 0; i < gpu_count; i++)); 
do
    range_width=$((interval + (i < remainder)))
    end=$((start + range_width - 1))
    ./blender/blender -b -P render.py -- $start $end $i &
    start=$((end + 1))
done
wait
```

```py
# render.py
import bpy
import sys
start = int(sys.argv[-3])
end = int(sys.argv[-2])
select_dev = int(sys.argv[-1])
bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA"
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = "GPU"
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
cycles_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
cycles_prefs.refresh_devices()
for device in cycles_prefs.devices:
    device.use = False
i = 0
for device in cycles_prefs.devices:
    if device.type == 'CUDA':
        if i == select_dev:
            device.use = True
        i = i + 1
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="/root/bl_remote/job.blend")
output_path = "/root/bl_remote/output/"
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG' 
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path + "img"  
bpy.context.scene.frame_start = start
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = end
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
print("-----------------")
for device in cycles_prefs.devices:        
    print("Device in use:", device.name, device.type, "Is in use:", device.use)
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

**Output result:**

```
"-----------------"
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 CUDA Is in use: False
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 CUDA Is in use: True
Device in use: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor CPU Is in use: False
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 OPTIX Is in use: False
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 OPTIX Is in use: False
"-----------------"
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 CUDA Is in use: True
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 CUDA Is in use: False
Device in use: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor CPU Is in use: False
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 OPTIX Is in use: False
Device in use: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 OPTIX Is in use: False
```

Why isn't the specified GPU being utilized as intended?

[image]